# "Bad request" on creating new session under CentOS, Firefox and Xvfb

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, centos, capybara, xvfb

When on `Mac OS X 10.10`, `Mozilla Firefox 38.3.0` and `java version "1.7.0_79"` I start Selenium hub and node:

> java -jar selenium-2.47.1.jar -role hub
>
> java -jar selenium-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hubHost 127.0.0.1

and run this test:

```
require "rspec"
require "capybara/rspec"

Capybara.app_host = "https://fb.*****.com/"

require "selenium/webdriver"

Capybara.register_driver :my_driver do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  desired_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox firefox_profile: profile
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    desired_capabilities: desired_capabilities,
    browser: :remote,
    url: "http://#{ENV["HUB_ADDRESS"]}:4444/wd/hub",
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :my_driver


feature "my feature" do

  scenario "my scenario" do
    visit ""
  end

end
```

it goes fine with:

> HUB_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1 rspec test.rb

---

When I run it on `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`, `Mozilla Firefox 38.3.0` and `openjdk version "1.8.0_51"` with:

> java -jar selenium-2.47.1.jar -role hub
>
> DISPLAY=:1 java -jar selenium-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hubHost 127.0.0.1

and Xvfb:

> Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24

it fails with this test log:

```
  1) my feature my scenario
     Failure/Error: visit ""
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Bad request
       Command duration or timeout: 199 milliseconds
       Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
       System info: host: 'vs01.*****.me', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab108.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver (org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException)
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):62:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):45:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):422:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):206:in `createThrowable'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):158:in `throwIfResponseFailed'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):595:in `execute'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):242:in `startSession'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):128:in `<init>'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):223:in `<init>'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):216:in `<init>'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):134:in `<init>'
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):62:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):45:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):422:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider(DefaultDriverProvider.java):103:in `callConstructor'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider(DefaultDriverProvider.java):97:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory(DefaultDriverFactory.java):60:in `newInstance'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):222:in `call'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):1:in `call'
     # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):266:in `run'
     # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):176:in `run'
     # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1142:in `runWorker'
     # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):617:in `run'
     # [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):745:in `run'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:71:in `assert_ok'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:657:in `raw_execute'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:122:in `create_session'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:87:in `initialize'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in `visit'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
     # /Users/nakilon/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test_min.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

hub log:

```
18:20:59.994 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=false, nativeEvents=false, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQAAAAIAJ2SOEcGjvwlZwMAA...}]
18:20:59.994 INFO - Available nodes: [http://*****:5555]
18:20:59.995 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node http://*****:5555
18:20:59.995 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, platform=LINUX}
```

and node log:

```
18:21:00.008 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=false, nativeEvents=false, browserName=firefo
x, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, firefox_profile=
UEsDBBQAAAAIAJ2SOEcGjvwlZwMAA...}]])
18:21:00.018 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=false, nativeEvents=false, browserName=fire
fox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, firefox_profil
e=UEsDBBQAAAAIAJ2SOEcGjvwlZwMAA...}]
18:21:02.219 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'vs01.*****.me', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab108.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:58)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:175)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'vs01.*****.me', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab108.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Bad request
Command duration or timeout: 199 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'vs01.*****.me', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab108.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:134)
        ... 14 more
18:21:02.224 WARN - Exception: Bad request
Command duration or timeout: 199 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'vs01.*****.me', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-042stab108.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

I've tried to mock capabilities with json obtained from Mac OS test run logging, but it didn't help.

UPD: found stack trace at `http://vs01.*****.me:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`:

```
{
  "status": 13,
  "value": {
    "message": "Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]",
    "class": "org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException",
    "stackTrace": [
      {
        "fileName": "ActiveTestSessions.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions",
        "methodName": "getExistingSession",
        "lineNumber": 110
      },
      {
        "fileName": "Registry.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry",
        "methodName": "getExistingSession",
        "lineNumber": 423
      },
      {
        "fileName": "RequestHandler.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler",
        "methodName": "getSession",
        "lineNumber": 238
      },
      {
        "fileName": "RequestHandler.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler",
        "methodName": "process",
        "lineNumber": 119
      },
      {
        "fileName": "DriverServlet.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet",
        "methodName": "process",
        "lineNumber": 83
      },
      {
        "fileName": "DriverServlet.java",
        "className": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet",
        "methodName": "doGet",
        "lineNumber": 61
      },
      {
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
        "methodName": "service",
        "lineNumber": 707
      },
      {
        "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
        "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
        "methodName": "service",
        "lineNumber": 820
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ServletHolder.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHolder",
        "methodName": "handle",
        "lineNumber": 565
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler",
        "methodName": "doHandle",
        "lineNumber": 479
      },
      {
        "fileName": "SessionHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler",
        "methodName": "doHandle",
        "lineNumber": 225
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler",
        "methodName": "doHandle",
        "lineNumber": 1031
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ServletHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler",
        "methodName": "doScope",
        "lineNumber": 406
      },
      {
        "fileName": "SessionHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler",
        "methodName": "doScope",
        "lineNumber": 186
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ContextHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler",
        "methodName": "doScope",
        "lineNumber": 965
      },
      {
        "fileName": "ScopedHandler.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ScopedHandler",
        "methodName": "handle",
        "lineNumber": 117
      },
      {
        "fileName": "HandlerWrapper.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.HandlerWrapper",
        "methodName": "handle",
        "lineNumber": 111
      },
      {
        "fileName": "Server.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server",
        "methodName": "handle",
        "lineNumber": 349
      },
      {
        "fileName": "AbstractHttpConnection.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection",
        "methodName": "handleRequest",
        "lineNumber": 452
      },
      {
        "fileName": "BlockingHttpConnection.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection",
        "methodName": "handleRequest",
        "lineNumber": 47
      },
      {
        "fileName": "AbstractHttpConnection.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection",
        "methodName": "headerComplete",
        "lineNumber": 884
      },
      {
        "fileName": "AbstractHttpConnection.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler",
        "methodName": "headerComplete",
        "lineNumber": 938
      },
      {
        "fileName": "HttpParser.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser",
        "methodName": "parseNext",
        "lineNumber": 634
      },
      {
        "fileName": "HttpParser.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser",
        "methodName": "parseAvailable",
        "lineNumber": 230
      },
      {
        "fileName": "BlockingHttpConnection.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection",
        "methodName": "handle",
        "lineNumber": 66
      },
      {
        "fileName": "SocketConnector.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint",
        "methodName": "run",
        "lineNumber": 254
      },
      {
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool",
        "methodName": "runJob",
        "lineNumber": 599
      },
      {
        "fileName": "QueuedThreadPool.java",
        "className": "org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3",
        "methodName": "run",
        "lineNumber": 534
      },
      {
        "fileName": "Thread.java",
        "className": "java.lang.Thread",
        "methodName": "run",
        "lineNumber": 745
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

UPD: tried also selenium 2.47.0 and 2.46.0 (with gem 2.46.1) -- can't degrade further, because don't know how to degrade Firefox on CentOS.

UPD: added logging remote http requests and omitted custom profile creation -- still fails right after this:

```
12:37:25.906    post        {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","version":"","platform":"ANY","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"nativeEvents":false,"rotatable":false}}
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was in that in `/etc/hosts` there was:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

instead of:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/431#issuecomment-133793667

After edit you should restart hub/node.